# Using Net::SSH::Perl with public key

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, ssh, perlnetssh

I want to gain access to an AWS Instance using Perl. I can access the instance from commandline like this:

```
ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ubuntu@ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but my code doesn't work:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH::Perl;

$user = "ubuntu";
$host = "ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com";
@KEYFILE = "my-key-pair.pem";
$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, debug=>1, identity_files=>\@KEYFILE);
$ssh->login($user);
```

As I mentioned I'm new to this concept, it might be a simple solution, I couldn't find a solution online, hopefully you can help me.

the output is this:

```
atakanarikan@atakanarikanhplaptop:~/Desktop$ perl remotecomp
atakanarikanhplaptop: Reading configuration data /home/atakanarikan/.ssh/config
atakanarikanhplaptop: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
atakanarikanhplaptop: Connecting to ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, port 22.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1

atakanarikanhplaptop: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
atakanarikanhplaptop: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.37, protocol version 2.0.
.takanarikanhplaptop: No compat match: OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
atakanarikanhplaptop: Connection established.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
atakanarikanhplaptop: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
atakanarikanhplaptop: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Host 'ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the host key.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Computing shared secret key.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Verifying server signature.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Waiting for NEWKEYS message.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Send NEWKEYS.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Enabling encryption/MAC/compression.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Sending request for user-authentication service.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Service accepted: ssh-userauth.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Trying empty user-authentication request.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Next method to try is publickey.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Trying pubkey authentication with key file 'my-key-pair.pem'
atakanarikanhplaptop: Will not query passphrase for 'my-key-pair.pem' in batch mode.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Loading private key failed.
Permission denied at remotecomp line 8.
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work." What error messages or other symptoms are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines

```
atakanarikanhplaptop: Will not query passphrase for 'my-key-pair.pem' in batch mode.
atakanarikanhplaptop: Loading private key failed.
```

seem to point to the issue. Your private key is protected by a passphrase, and when you try to use it, it wants to ask you for it, but can't in batch mode.

I think you're going to have to remove the passphrase from your private key to use this module. There are many tools, including OpenSSL, that can do that for you. Just search the documentation for removing a passphrase from a key.

Comment: yes, this seemed to work. thank you for your answer!